# Fire event when queue is almost full

Tags: java, events, data-structures, event-listener, blockingqueue

I have a use-case where I am populating my `blocking queue` with a lot of data.
Now, I want to fire an event(call a method) when this queue gets 90%(*arbitrary value*) full.

I want to achieve this so that I can perform an operation on the bulk data from the queue.

For this, I am thinking of extending one of the implementations of `BlockingQueue` such as `LinkedBlockingQueue` and overriding the `put(...)` method and do something like:

```
...
@Override
public void put(E e) {
    super.put(e);
    if(this.percentageUsed() >= 90)
        fireEvent(this);
}
...
```

And write my logic to deal with the `BlockingQueue` object in the `fireEvent` method.

This could very well be done using a scheduler to poll the size of the queue every `n` `seconds`, but if I had many of these queues in my application, it would create havoc to handle all the schedulers. Also, this approach would keep everything in a single class file and much cleaner code.

Please provide an expert insight into this approach.

Comment: What do you need exactly? yes, for what you want you need to override the method and provide your own implementation that calls previous implementations and adds something mor. This is called Observer and Proxy.

Comment: I need an event listener for when the queue in `X%` filled.

Comment: so create it. Do you have problems in how to design it? if so - please look at Observer and Proxy. If not, please explain.

Comment: I have designed the structure but wanted a critical review on this approach. Whether it's a good idea to do so, etc.

Comment: Can't say: I have no info on the model you're working with. You ask how good is a dress by the color of the needle. Not really going to work. You ask if there is a catch? well, any structure, like list, map or queue are normally self-expanding, meaning they will increase in size once they reach certain limit. I.e. you will never reach 90% load, unless you have 2^16 items. So you better decide on independand value of maximum size. Otherwise it boils down to bigger picture :)

Comment: Good point. I asked this question specifically for `blockingqueue` where the capacity will be defined beforehand. I wish to drain out the contents of queue and log a message when the queue fills X%.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar problem, I ended up writing the following Class:

```
public class EventBlockingQueue<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int capacity;
    private double eventThreshold;
    private transient Consumer<EventBlockingQueue<E>> eventHandler;

    /**
     * 
     * @param capacity 
     * @param eventThreshold percentage value X (X => {X∈Z    1<=X<=100} ) at which the event is fired
     * @param eventHandler method to be fired at threshold barrier
     */
    public EventBlockingQueue(int capacity, double eventThreshold, Consumer eventHandler) {
        super(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.eventThreshold = eventThreshold;
        this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        boolean addResult = super.add(e);
        if(percentageUsed()>=eventThreshold && eventHandler!=null)
            eventHandler.accept(this);
        return addResult;
    }

    private int percentageUsed() {
        return size()*100/capacity;
    }


}
```